# how to select a selector which is appended by ajax without refresh the page

Tags: ajax

I'm creating a list of clients by ajax(jquery) including 'add client', 'edit client', 'remove client'.

With ajax, I wrote the code to append a new client with $("#list").append(...) to my list as following:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "traitement.php",
            data: {nom, prenom, email},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function () {
                $("#reponse")
                    .hide()
                    .html("<span class='sucess'> Client ajouté avec succès. </span>")
                    .fadeIn(1000);  
                $("input").val('');
                $("#list").append("<tr id='New'><td>" + id + "</td><td>" + nom + "</td><td>" + prenom + "</td><td>" + email + "</td>"+"<td id = 'editNew'><button><i class='fa fa-edit'></i></button></td>"+"<td  id = 'deleteNew'><button><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></button></td>"+"</tr>");
            },
            error: function() {
                $("#reponse")    
                .html("<span class='error'> Une erreur s'est produite. </span>");
            }            
        });
```

Now, i would like to select #editNew or #deleteNew to modify my list of clients without refresh the page.

The problem is that after append "#new" to my HTML by ajax. This element ** is displayed but not yet in the Page Source**. So that, i can not choose it.

Could you please to give me some ideas about how can I append an element and choose this element without refresh the page with ajax, please!

Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Let try with this code, i hope can help you.

```js
$.ajax({
                type : "POST", 
                url : "traitement.php", 
                data : {nom, prenom, email},
                beforeSend: function() {},
                success: function(response) {
                    $("input").val('');
                    $("#list").html('');
                    if (response.notification) {
                        var list_tr = '';
                        response.data.forEach(d => {
                            list_tr += "<tr id='New'><td>" + d.id + "</td><td>" + d.nom + "</td><td>" + d.prenom + "</td><td>" + d.email + "</td>"+"<td id = 'editNew'><button><i class='fa fa-edit'></i></button></td>"+"<td  id = 'deleteNew'><button><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></button></td>"+"</tr>";
                        });
                    } else {
                      $("#list").html("<tr><td colspan='5'><p></p></td></tr>");
                    }
                    $("#list").html(list_tr);
                },
                complete: function(response) {
                  if (response.notification) {
                    $("#reponse")
                      .html("<span class='sucess'> Client ajouté avec succès. </span>")
                      .fadeIn(1000);
                  } else {
                    $("#reponse")
                      .html("<span class='danger'> Client ajouté avec fail. </span>")
                      .fadeIn(1000);
                  }
                },
                error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                    console.log( 'The following error occured: ' + textStatus, errorThrown );
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
Your idea is create a list_tr then you replace inner content HTML of selector #list by list_tr by $("#list").html(list_tr); 

The problem here is by using command .html or .append, the data will be displayed as we wish but the source code of page (View Page Source Code) does not contain the adding items by .append or .html.
 
So that, we can not modify these items if we want.

The aime of my question is how to enable this task, that means change somethings in order to the adding items will be included in source code of page without reload the page.